# Good books for Duration Analysis

Tags: survival, references

What are some good books for learning/mastering duration analysis at an intermediate/advanced level? Would be interested in both modern suggestions as well as classics.

Comment: Just noticed now that its a duplication.

Comment: Wow, I never know it's also called "Duration Analysis," which sounds so much more politically correct.